# I want to paste some rows from one workbook to another based on some criteria in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing the problem in the last 3 line of code, I simply want to copy the selected values into another workbook, kindly help me with that.

```
Sub y()
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1)    
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("B.xlsx").Worksheets(1)    
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook    

    Lastrowo = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrowc = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Lastrowo
        If ws1.Cells(i, "AF").Value = "X" Then
            ws1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    For j = 2 To Lastrowc
        If ws2.Cells(j, "AF").Value = "X" Then
            ws2.Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next j

    ws2.Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove   
    ws2.Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[A.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1,1,FALSE)),""Add"","""")"    
    ws2.Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=ws2.Range("B2:B" & Lastrowc), Type:=xlFillDefault

    With ws2.UsedRange    
        .Copy        
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    For k = 2 To Lastrowc   
        If ws2.Cells(k, "B").Value = "Add" Then
            'in these 3 lines is the issue   
            ws2.Rows(k).EntireRow.Copy   
            Windows("Addition.xlsm").Activate    
            Workbooks("Addition.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Rows(2).paste   
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, put Option Explicit at the top of your module above Sub y() and declare all your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to paste by values:

Replace

```
ws2.Rows(k).EntireRow.Copy   
Windows("Addition.xlsm").Activate    
Workbooks("Addition.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Rows(2).paste
```

with

```
ws2.Rows(k).EntireRow.Copy   
Workbooks("Addition.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Rows(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: can you explain why you think that should help and what the issue is with that code? I agree that using `.Activate` is a bad practice and it should be avoided, but that doesn't mean that this code does not work. So how would that help?

Comment: The problem faced by yashika vaish might not be runtime error. Perhaps, he was getting unexpected result when copying formulas that refer to other ranges.